# What is the name of the Doraemon episode where Nobita is very intelligent?

Tags: doraemon

Once I saw an episode of Doraemon on TV, in which Nobita is a genius.  He always scores full marks in the tests.  His mom is happy with it.  When he tells her that he is going out, his mother allows him by saying that he often does extra studies etc. I can't remember the episode's name.
Can anyone name the episode? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess [this](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8A%E3%81%97%E6%A9%9F). It is not making Nobita intelligent, but going back to childhood with 'current' memory.

Comment: @sundowner thank you. But I could not find the video. Can you please mention the episode's name, so I can watch?

Comment: Generally it is the same as the tool's name. According to googling, it is Doraemon 137 誕生日は計画的に / 人生やりなおし機.

Comment: Possibly "Escape From Score Zero" in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_(English_dub)_episodes). I've no idea which episodes are aired abroad.

Comment: @sundowner thank you for your efforts. But sadly, this is not the episode I am talking about. It was one of the old episodes (when the animation style of Doraemon was not changed to the current style). I can't find it anywhere. Can you please name the episode?Thank you by the way.

Comment: @sundowner sorry, but it is not the one I am talking about. Thank you by the way friend.